# Editing AWX CSS in Docker Container

Tags: css, docker, ansible, containers, ansible-awx

I'm hoping someone has some expertise with AWX running as a Docker container. We've switched on the Azure AD authentication and I'd like to hide the local login modal via CSS. It seems that the CSS files are generated on startup and any changes to app.xxxxxxxx.css in /var/lib/awx/public/static/css don't seem to have any effect, and are newly generated upon restart anyway. I was wondering if there was a source CSS file I could edit so I can make changes and keep them through a reboot. Any help would be appreciated.

Docker image: ansible/awx_web
AWX Version: 7.0.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Here was my solution to this.

I copied the static folder from the awx_web container:

```
docker cp id:/var/lib/awx/public/static/ /somefolder/static/
```

This will copy all of the HTML/CSS/JS elements of the web application to a local folder so that you can edit the files and keep your changes through a reboot.
This particular issue required me edit the app.xxxxxxx.css file in /static/css/ and find the styling for "btn LoginModal-signInButton" and change the visibility to hidden.


The next step was to mount the locally copied static folder from earlier to the static folder inside the container. I navigated to the 'awxcompose' directory (in my case it was /var/awxcompose) and added the following line to the docker-compose.yml file under awx_web > volumes:

```
- "somefolder/static/:/var/lib/awx/public/static/:ro"
```

Then once I was ready to push my changes, I re-made the container using docker-compose:

```
docker-compose down && docker-compose up -d
```

And to make sure the containers remained in this state after a reboot, I added the following line to my crontab:

```
@reboot docker-compose -f /var/awxcompose/docker-compose.yml up -d
```

---

Comment: Please provide specifics in the post, as this statement does not really address the original question.